# Does Kotlin support expression trees?

Tags: expression-trees, kotlin

It seems that there was a plan to include this feature in the language, but I cannot find anything in documentation about it. Does Kotlin support expression trees? Is this feature still on the roadmap?

Comment: The link above is to an "April Fools" joke by the Kotlin team, it is NOT a feature of Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Currently Kotlin (and for 1.0) does not support expression trees.  There has been similar talk in the Kotlin chat on Slack that something might be coming in the future after 1.0.  It is best if you go there, to the channel `#language-proposals` and discuss future features there that are under discussion and have no concrete answer. [Kotlin Slack](http://kotlinslackin.herokuapp.com/).